# Android Webview with local Javascript file

Tags: javascript, android-studio, android-webview

I am currently doing a project to build an android app. I need to load a HTML file with local Javascript, I placed the files in the directory folder named **Assets**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQIUk.png)

I have changed the CSS & JS directory in the HTML file like most of the tutorials did. The styling CSS file is loaded without any problem, however, the JS file that contain all the important functions seems not loaded. Below are script tag lines.

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/js/hanzi-writer.min.js"></script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/js/test.js"></script>
```

I have tried several ways like setJavaScriptEnabled(true), setDomStorageEnabled(true) but it still remain the same.

I am also pretty sure the HTML, CSS and JS all working well as I have tried to open it in a Desktop Chrome browser.

Thanks if anyone can help.

Comment: Did you do any debugging? Did you check the error log?

Comment: Im pretty sure the javascript file is working fine as I already tested before adding it with the HTML into the android project.

While in the android WebView, the HTML file was loaded correctly with the CSS styling, however the javascript function is not working when I press those button.

Comment: Sorry, this does not answer my question.

Comment: What Im trying to tell is that, if the Javascript works in the Desktop browser, it shouldnt have any problem when it's imported into the android studio's WebView right? Sorry if my sentence sound stupid, because Im a newbie in programming.